# Is there a way to implement setOnDateListener within a fragment and have it send data to another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, event-listener

I'm working in android studio want to set up a `setOnDateListener` for a `CalendarView` object. The `CalendarView` object is inside of a fragment that is generated programmatically. The only problem is when trying to send the data from the calendar to the `MainActivity` file. It keeps saying something about a null object reference.

I've tried everything. Currently I'm trying to use an interface which I have no experience with. I've tried moving the listener everywhere. Nothing seems to work. Here's the minimal (it's a lot sorry)

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentEntry.Callback {

    FragmentHome fragmentHome;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // add the fragments
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentHome(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentEntry(), "Entry");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    public void sendDate(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        fragmentHome.text(day, month, year);
    }
}
```

**FragmentHome:**

```
    public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {

        // empty constructor, onCreate, and onCreateView

        public void text(int day, int month, int year) {
            TextView textView = getText().findViewById(R.id.textView);
            String text = String.format(R.string.month + "/" + R.string.day + "/" + R.string.year, month, day, year);
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

**FragmentEntry:**

```
    public class FragmentEntry extends Fragment {

        public Callback callback;

        // empty constructor, onCreate

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry, container, false);

            CalendarView calendarView = v.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
            calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int y, int m, int d) {
                    callback.sendDate(d, m, y);
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Like I said I've tried moving around the date listener but it is currently here. I expect the `sendDate` function call to well, function properly but the Logcat says otherwise. It keeps saying

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.fragmentcommunicationtest.FragmentEntry$Callback.sendDate(int, int, int)' on a null object reference
```

Even when not using an interface I had the same exact problem with the whole null object reference. I don't know where else to go. I've tried everything and I expect at this point it's going to be something that I have overlooked. help

Comment: You need to initialize your callback. Please show the code where you are  creating `FragmentHome` from `MainActivity` .

Comment: @sunilsunny as requested, fragment home implementation was added.

Comment: ok see my answer.

Comment: One more error I noticed is this `getText().findViewById(R.id.textView);`. You can't find the view like that.

Comment: @sunilsunny my bad that is meant to say `getView()`. My mistake.

Comment: it's still wrong. That textview is only available in your fragment view but you are trying to find it from textview itself. I will do an edit in my answer just check if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing your `callback` object, from `MainActivity` try this

```
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentEntry(this), "Entry");
```

And create a constructor in `FragmentEntry` with callback as the parameter (I believe that's where you want the callback from).

```
public FragmentEntry(Callback callback) 
{
 this.callback = callback
}
```

Now the callback is intialized.

**Edit**

For the 2nd issue  `TextView textView = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);` this is wrong because you are trying to find the view from `TextView`.

Try this:

Create a global TextView, get the view from `onCreateView` and set it in the 
callback.

```
TextView textView
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    return v;
}
```

And then set the value like this.

```
public void text(int day, int month, int year) {
    String text = String.format(R.string.month + "/" + R.string.day + "/" + R.string.year, month, day, year);
    textView.setText(text);
}
```

**Edit 2**
you are right `fragmentHome` is null indeed. Try this

```
fragmentHome = new FragmentHome(); 
adapter.addFragment(fragmentHome, "Home");
```

Comment: Ok this got me farther than I have been and I thank you for that sincerely. But now it complains about the call to `text(int, int, int)` coming from the `sendDate` function in `FragmentEntry`. Sorry to keep asking it's just been bugging me for a while.

Comment: hey mate. You're the only one that is actually helping me with this so I do have another question. I've done some testing and found out that the problem is coming from `fragmentHome.text()`. Even with arguments it complains about a `null object reference`. I think maybe I need to initialize `fragmentHome` differently?

Comment: dude I can't thank you enough. You were the only one willing to help me with this problem that I have been stuck on for almost 2 weeks now. You don't even know how grateful I am. Thanks again!

Comment: That's ok mate. You can accept my answer, if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend way to communicate between fragments or to activities is through ViewModel component. Refer below to see the advantages of VieModel over interface way of communication for your case :
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing